# SQL Server deleting substring from given start and end characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function

I am doing a project where I'm working with the chemical formula of some products.

There are many product formula entries in the database containing `<sub>` and `<span>` tags as in the following sequence:

```
C<sub>7</sub>H<sub><span style="font-size: 10px;">8</sub>O<sub>3</sub>S.H<sub>2</sub>O
```

I'm looking for a way to get rid of the span tags and their content (I don't want to remove the sub tags). For example, in the example above, I would like to get rid of this part:

```
<span style="font-size: 10px;">
```

Basically, the function would need to delete everything between the given start and end substrings.
Is there a SQL Server function which would delete everything between '**<span**' and '**>**'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to look in `REPLACE` with `PATINDEX`.

Comment: Did you try using REPLACE function?

Comment: I would *assume* that the tag could have other values, like `'<span style="font-size: 12px;">'` or even `'<span style="font-size: 8px; font-style:arial">'`, so `REPLACE` won't work there. Honestly, SQL Server does not excel at string manipulation. A tool with Regex support would be much better at this.

Comment: Could a string have multiple Span tags that need removing too?

Comment: @Larnu You are right! The tag can have multiple values. It can also have multiple span tags.

Answer (score 3):

*If* we assume that there can be multiple `span` tags, and `</span>` need to be removed, then we have to do some ugly SQL. Like I said in the comments, ideally don't use T-SQL to do this, and use a language that supports Regex:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('C<sub>7</sub>H<sub><span style="font-size: 10px;">8</sub>O<sub>3</sub>S.H<sub>2</sub>O'),
                ('C<sub>7</sub>H<sub><span style="font-size: 12px;">8</sub>O<sub>3</sub></span>S.H<sub>2</sub>O'),
                ('C<sub>7</sub>H<sub><span style="font-size: 8px; font-style:arial">8</sub>O<sub>3</sub></span>S.H<sub>2</sub>O'),
                ('C<sub>7</sub>H<sub><span style="font-size: 12px;">8</sub>O<sub>3</sub></span><span style="font-size: 8px;">S.H</span><sub>2</sub>O'),
                ('C<sub>7</sub>H<sub>8</sub>O<sub>3</sub>S.H<sub>2</sub>O'))V(YourString)),
rCTE AS(
    SELECT YT.YourString,
           V.CI,
           CASE V.CI WHEN 0 THEN YT.YourString ELSE STUFF(YT.YourString,V.CI,CHARINDEX('>',YT.YourString,V.CI) - V.CI +1 ,'') END AS NewString,
           1 AS Iteration
    FROM YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('<span',YT.YourString)))V(CI)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.YourString,
           V.CI,
           CASE V.CI WHEN 0 THEN r.NewString ELSE STUFF(r.NewString,V.CI,CHARINDEX('>',r.NewString,V.CI) - V.CI +1 ,'') END AS NewString,
           r.Iteration + 1
    FROM rCTE r
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('<span',r.NewString)))V(CI)
    WHERE V.CI > 0)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       REPLACE(NewString,'</span>','')
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YourString ORDER BY Iteration DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu). Span tag could have other values. Considering string could have multiple span tag, We can try below

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'C<sub>7</sub>H<sub><span style="font-size: 10px;">8</sub>O<sub>3</sub>S.H<sub>2</sub>O'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @String AS Formula
    WHERE @String LIKE '%<span%'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT STUFF(Formula, CHARINDEX('<span', Formula, 1), CHARINDEX('>', Formula, CHARINDEX('<span', Formula, 1))-CHARINDEX('<span', Formula, 1)+1, '') 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Formula LIKE '%<span%'

)
SELECT TOP 1 Formula 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY LEN(Formula)
```

Comment: FYI, it's not `;WITH`. `;` is a statement terminator, not a "beginningator"; it goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not the start of statements that require the *previous* statement to be correctly terminated.

Comment: @Larnu Yupe, I know its statement terminator, which we generally use at the end of the statement. But it's just my habit to use ;WITH instead of WITH. :)